# Following instruction for drag and drop 3d object unity but not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

Hi so i have followed every instruction from youtube videos (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NMt6Ibxa_XQ) but in the game mode i still cant drag and drop my cube, the cube just stay still when i click and drag it. This problem really gave me a headache i’m pretty sure i have followed every detail from the video and repeat it over and over, thank’s for your time and help i really appreciate and need it, thank youi

Comment: I'm sorry, but you aren't going to find an answer to that here. This site is for programming questions only. You might find help on [Unity's site](https://answers.unity.com/index.html).

Comment: Welcome to SO im new here too. but i know Unity. i left an answer down below! check it out. Jimenemex is right though, not really a programming question per se. but IMHO you should have left a comment with the tutorial maker, about there lack of explanation.

Comment: According to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), if a question is about "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" then it is fine. I believe this falls under that category.

Comment: That being said, you are much more likely to get an answer if you tell us what you've done so far in more detail. Perhaps attach some code snippets where you suspect the problem might be, or some screenshots of the inspector for the cube you can't move.

Comment: i checked the video he watched and am willing to bet its because he dosnt have a rigid body and/or collider  on his cube

Answer (score 2):

in order for your cube to take the `OnMouseDown()` event you need to add a `collider` and `rigidbody`.  click the cube, go to the properties on the right and click 
`add component - physics - cube collider`
then do the same, for the rigid body
`add component - physics - rigid body.`

dont forget to set the `rigidbody` to `kinematic`, or set the `gravity scale` to 0 if you dont want it to fall out of the scene

Answer (score 1):

use this script in order to drad and drop 3D Objects :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour
{  
    private bool _mouseState;
    private GameObject target;
    public Vector3 screenSpace;
    public Vector3 offset;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        // Debug.Log(_mouseState);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            target = GetClickedObject (out hitInfo);
            if (target != null) {
                _mouseState = true;
                screenSpace = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (target.transform.position);
                offset = target.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenSpace.z));
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
            _mouseState = false;
        }
        if (_mouseState) {
            //keep track of the mouse position
            var curScreenSpace = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenSpace.z);

            //convert the screen mouse position to world point and adjust with offset
            var curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (curScreenSpace) + offset;

            //update the position of the object in the world
            target.transform.position = curPosition;
        }
    }


    GameObject GetClickedObject (out RaycastHit hit)
    {
        GameObject target = null;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, out hit)) {
            target = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }

        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is "Drag and drop manager" and can have only one instance in the project otherwise bad things are going to happen. Dont attach to prefabs.